# filtering grid with date and time with Kendo UI using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid

I have a grid with date and time part like in the picture below. But in this way filtering doesn't work because I cannot choose date without time. So the question is, how I can implement this grid with options to choose date and time at the same time, like 12.01.2016 at 12:37 (not only 12:00, 12:30, 13:00 etc as in the datetimepicker).

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, this is the expected behaviour of DateTimePicker. It haves two buttons to choose date or time separatedly. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, but in this example I cannot choose 4:36 for example, as I can see it can be only 4:00, 4:30...

Comment: Hm, now I got what you mean. In fact you have to type those values, otherwise the time list would be huge: https://jsfiddle.net/1owrp7tq/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, thanks! this I wanted) but it is really huge and I think that it will be better to use filtering without time part ahah)